# Write array to Three.WebGLRenderTarget

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm trying to port the example here: david.li/waves from raw webgl to three. I am using WebGl rendertargets to substitute the textures he uses, which seems to work ok except for one of the textures, namely the pingPhaseTexture.

Most of his textures are created like this, where buildTexture's data parameter is null:

```
var buildTexture = function (gl, unit, format, type, width, height, data, wrapS, wrapT, minFilter, magFilter) {
    var texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + unit);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, type, data);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, wrapS);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, wrapT);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, minFilter);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, magFilter);
    return texture;
};
initialSpectrumTexture = buildTexture(gl, INITIAL_SPECTRUM_UNIT, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, RESOLUTION, RESOLUTION, null, gl.REPEAT, gl.REPEAT, gl.NEAREST, gl.NEAREST);
```

Which I ported to THREE like this:

```
this.initialSpectrumFramebuffer = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(RESOLUTION, RESOLUTION, renderTargetNearestClampFloatParams);
```

This seems to work ok but there is one texture he uses which is populated by an array which he passes in as the data parameter:

```
 var phaseArray = new Float32Array(RESOLUTION * RESOLUTION * 4);
    for (var i = 0; i < RESOLUTION; i += 1) {
        for (var j = 0; j < RESOLUTION; j += 1) {
            phaseArray[i * RESOLUTION * 4 + j * 4] = Math.random() * 2.0 * Math.PI;
            phaseArray[i * RESOLUTION * 4 + j * 4 + 1] = 0;
            phaseArray[i * RESOLUTION * 4 + j * 4 + 2] = 0;
            phaseArray[i * RESOLUTION * 4 + j * 4 + 3] = 0;
        }
    }
 var pingPhaseTexture = buildTexture(gl, PING_PHASE_UNIT, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, RESOLUTION, RESOLUTION, phaseArray, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE, gl.NEAREST, gl.NEAREST);
```

How can I pass phaseArray as the framebuffer for a WebGLRenderTarget? I tried using a DataTexture instead but that raises a whole bunch of other problems when it comes time to render.

Comment: What "whole other bunch of problems"? Don't you want to use the `DataTexture` as the seed for your simulation, and then ping-pong between the `WebGLRenderTargets`? Also, see: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_shaders_ocean.html.

Comment: @WestLangley, I set up the texture using a data texture as you suggested and looked at the example you mentioned (as well as this this one: http://jsfiddle.net/EqLL9/4/)

I don't get any errors anymore, but all I see is a black plane. I set up a fiddle to show what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/ttmike/cQ9yM/8/

PS here is the original:
http://david.li/waves/waves.js

Comment: I can't help you debug your code, but I can suggest that you look at another example of GPGPU within the framework of three.js: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_gpgpu_birds.html. Also, if you are getting a black plane, then back up to a super simple three.js GPGPU framework that produces something, and then add on pieces from there. I would definitely like to see you succeed.

Comment: @WestLangley I am making progress, do you know if it is possible to draw with TRIANGLE_STRIP in three? I know Ribbon used to implement it but thats been deprecated in r66

Comment: It is not possible within the current framework.

Comment: @WestLangley I see that now, had to write an extension to renderer to draw triangle strips. Can post it if you think it would be helpful.

Comment: Oh, yes. That would be helpful. :-)

Comment: Eep will have to work on it some more, seems it bugs out under general arrays :S sorry about that

Comment: I hope you can find a way to port the code without hacking the library -- or making direct WebGL calls -- but if you do, please share. These kinds of experiments are great for finding ways to improve three.js.

Comment: @WestLangley I got it working (more or less), done entirely in the library! Only issue to sort out now is the way threejs splits up geometries into blocks of 65k, as it is resulting in 'bands' during rendering if the geometry gets too big. See the demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ttmike/cQ9yM/22/

:)

Comment: +1 `BufferGeometry` should solve that in the next release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem, and you can view my solution within the demo here:

http://www.routter.co.tt/Demo/Ocean

EDIT:
Now available as part of the r66 dev build in the examples section

enjoy! :)